# synchronizing a resource in executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using executor framework for carrying out a large task. I need to keep a count of how many have been completed for process status purpose. So i have created a singleton class with a counter to keep the count.

```
public class ProgramInitializationTracker {

    private static Map<String, Integer> programInitializedTracker = new HashMap<>();
    private static ProgramInitializationTracker instance;

    private ProgramInitializationTracker(){

    }

    public static ProgramInitializationTracker getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (ProgramInitializationTracker.class) {
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new ProgramInitializationTracker();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public Integer getProgramInitializedTracker(String key) {
        return programInitializedTracker.get(key);
    }

    public void setProgramInitializedTracker(String key, int value) {
        synchronized (ProgramInitializationTracker.class) {
            ProgramInitializationTracker.programInitializedTracker.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is only by synchronizing set method will not really ensure that i have correct value of count. As far as i could get multithreading. Do making get function also synchronized will help me. If no then what should i have done to make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to implement your own thread-safe access to a collection when Java already provides this for you.

You should use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Reads such as `get` do not block.

But rather than use an Integer type as the value stored in the map, you should use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which will ensure that multiple threads attempting to modify the value associated with the same key will be thread safe.

Comment: but the problem is with get also. suppose two thread get values (2). now first updated it to (3) and now second will be updating it to (3) again.

Comment: As i tried to say in the last line of my answer, Atomic integer prevents that from happening. Two threads cannot have a race condition if you use atomic integer.

Answer (score 0):

Under constraints you posted, simply sharing an instance of `AtomicInteger` between tasks you submit to an `ExecutorService` and a place you want to have a metric must do. `variant1` is for having single counter covering all tasks and `variant2` is for having counter per task type. This code is (should be) thread-safe.

```
@ThreadSafe
class Test {

    private static class CountingRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Nonnull
        private final Runnable actualTask;

        @Nonnull
        private final AtomicInteger submitted;

        public CountingRunnable(@Nonnull Runnable actualTask, @Nonnull AtomicInteger submitted) {
            this.actualTask = actualTask;
            this.submitted = submitted;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            actualTask.run();
            submitted.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        variant2();
    }

    private static void variant1() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        service.submit(new CountingRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }, counter));

        latch.await();
        System.out.println(counter.get());
        service.shutdown();
    }

    private enum TaskType {
        TYPE_1,
        TYPE_2
    }

    private static void variant2() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        final EnumMap<TaskType, AtomicInteger> metrics = new EnumMap<>(TaskType.class);
        metrics.put(TaskType.TYPE_1, new AtomicInteger());
        metrics.put(TaskType.TYPE_2, new AtomicInteger());

        service.submit(new CountingRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, metrics.get(TaskType.TYPE_1)));

        service.submit(new CountingRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, metrics.get(TaskType.TYPE_2)));

        latch.await();

        System.out.println("type 1: " + metrics.get(TaskType.TYPE_1));
        System.out.println("type 2: " + metrics.get(TaskType.TYPE_2));

        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```